# Post HTML form from ColdFusion to asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, coldfusion-8

I am working with a credit card payment gateway. The access to gateway is written in ColdFusion (8). I am developing a new web site in asp.net/C# and using this payment gateway in ColdFusion. I could sucessfully post data from HTML form in my asp.net page to ColdFusion page. After processing the payment the ColdFusion page posts back a form with data to the asp.net page.

```
<cfoutput>
  <form name="frmupdate" method="post" action="#return_url#">
    <input type="hidden" name="ordernumber" value="#order_no">
  </form>
</cfoutput>
```

The redirection is done correctly and debug point in asp.net page (return_url) is hit. When I try to access the form field "ordernumber" (Request.Form["ordernumber"]) it always returns null. Cannot change the logic in ColdFusion. Please give me a hint to make this work. Or any basic rule I have forgotten?

Comment: Your input is missing a hashmark. Instead of `...value="#order_no">` it should be `...value="#order_no#">`.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code should be:

```
<cfoutput>
  <form name="frmupdate" method="post" action="#return_url#">
    <input type="hidden" name="ordernumber" value="#order_no#">
  </form>
</cfoutput>
```